# How to fetch exact match using where clause in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-HotFix | Where-Object HotfixID -eq "KB97690" 
if ($?) {
    Write-Output "success"
} else {
    Write-Output "F"
}
```

The above code result, how to check exact match hotfixid, if it hotfixid not matching fully it should fail.

But they above code however its through success.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you are not good in writnig texts in english, consider asking a friend who is more familiar with the english language to help you out. Also take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take a look at the help center, especially [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you !!
sure,please suggest you understand my question or do  i need to clarify it.

Comment: @vel: judging from the close votes, some clarification would be helpful.

Comment: Yes i have fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other method:

```
Get-HotFix -Id "KB97690" -ErrorAction Ignore | %{"I found at least one item for it."}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing `$?`. This automatic variable contains the execution status of the last operation. Even if `Get-HotFix | Where-Object HotfixID -eq "KB97690"` has no result, the *execution* itself suceeds. That means, `if($?)` is `$true` for your script. You might be searching for a thing like:

```
$matchedUpdates = Get-HotFix | Where-Object {$_.HotfixID -eq "KB97690"}
if ($matchedUpdates) {
     Write-Host "I found at least one item for it."
}
```

There are many other ways to achieve what you are trying. Here we use the fact, that PowerShell equals an object / array with items to `$true` if provided to an if-statement and to `$false` if it's `$null`.

Comment: Thanks its working fine. could you please if you have any betterment solution because this code execution time is taking more.

Comment: No, your code and mine both take in average 400-500 msecs at my machine. (Win10, i7-4810MQ, 32GiB, PoSh 5.1)